# The key format 'AVRO' is not currently supported

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

i am following this blog in understanding ElasticSearchSink connector
https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/kafka-to-elasticsearch

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM TEST01 (ALPHA VARCHAR KEY,COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR)
       WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test01', PARTITIONS=1, FORMAT='AVRO');
```

got the following error
**The key format 'AVRO' is not currently supported.**

i am using **confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:latest** and **confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:latest**

As of Now, replaced **FORMAT='AVRO'** with **VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'**
didn't get any error, can anyone assist if this is the right way to go ?

Comment: 1) Don't use latest, use tagged versions 2) if you're going to follow a tutorial, don't modify it until you have it working... See image `confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.15.0`, listed in that repo

Comment: it shouldn't matter, but you can see in the readme.md file

Comment: It does matter, though.

Answer (score 1):

Avro key support is only a recent addition, [as of 0.15](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksqldb-0-15-features-updates/)

If you want to use the latest ksql features, you should be using the `confluentinc/ksqldb-server` image, which is newer than the "distribution package" `cp-ksqldb-server`, and what is actually used in that repo

ref https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#ksqldb